# How to break out of inner for loop and get back to parent for loop

Tags: c++, c

I have a code here,

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
    {
        //checking some conditions here for true or false
        if(false)
        {
            break out of this for loop;
        }
        else if(true)
        {
            printf("true");
        }
    }
}
```

i want to break out of inner for loop and continue with the outer loop . I tried to use `break` but the control moved out of the parent for loop also.

Any solution for this?

Comment: Are you *sure* that using `break` didn't work ?

Comment: `break;` should work, `if(false)` will never be executed, your condition is not correct?

Comment: break should work. are you sure the outer loop was broken or could it be that it ran through and subsequent calls of the inner loop were all broken so no output occurred?

Comment: `break/continue` only breaks/continues the current loop. Any outer loop will proceed as usual, unaffected by the `break/continue` in the inner loop.

Comment: `I tried to use break but the control moved out of the parent for loop also` can't be true. May be the condition for outer loop failed which you think happens due to the `break`.

Answer (score 9):

> I tried to use `break` but the control moved out of the parent for loop also.

You must be confused. `break` only breaks out of the innermost loop/switch, so it *can't* have stopped the outer loop too (unless by chance the outer loop was on its last iteration, which gave you this false impression).

When you are in doubt like this, you can either step through your code using a debugger, or at the very least insert "tracing" output in your code so that you can verify what it actually does:

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    printf("outer loop %d\n", i);
    for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
    {
        printf("inner loop %d\n", j);
        //checking some conditions here for true or false
        if(false)
        {
            printf("breaking out of inner loop\n");
            break;
        }
        else if(true)
        {
            printf("true in inner loop\n");
        }
    }
    printf("finishing the outer loop %d\n", i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes your code is correct and it must work as you have expected.
Unless you have compiled this one and execute something another. :-)

Answer (score 1):

> 6.8.6.3 The break statement
>
> Constraints
>
> 1 A break statement shall appear only in or as a switch body or loop body.
>
> Semantics
>
> 2 A break statement terminates execution of the smallest enclosing switch or iteration
> statement.

Quoted from ISO/IEC 9899:TC3

So your break should work, as you don't use any pre alpha compiler.

but the problem is more

```
if (false) //will never be executed, as false is ever fals
{
    //code gets never invoked
}
```

so you don't break out as you never invoke the `break;`

Answer (score 0):

If you use `break` in the inner loop then it will definitely move the control to the outer loop.

I think what you might be missing is to reset your false condition after coming out of the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

It's all based on logic on when you want to break out from the inner loops. Consider the following steps.

```
Do
    For Int x = 1 To 10
        Do
            Break, Break, Break
        Loop
    Next x
Loop
```

Try reconsidering your program logic and implement the break statements using flags.

If you want, you could just overcome by breaking from the inner loops by using the goto statements.

```
int num[5][5][5];

for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++)
    {
        for (int z = 0; z < 5; z++)
        {
            if (num[x][y][z] == 256)
            {
                cout << "Number has been found at location: " << x << y << z;
                //break the three for loops here, it's unnecessary to check any other locations
                goto finish;
            }
        }
    }
}
finish:
```

Comment: What's with the three breaks?

Comment: @Shahbaz, to break from do,for and do.

Answer (score 0):

Break only breaks the loop in which it is used 
and btw if that condition is false it will never execute

Comment: I am sorry , i should have not written if(false) . It has created a confusion here.But in my code i have it as true. So i will check what i am missing.

Comment: @leesei , how can i goto the parent for loop at if(some_condition)?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a flag and checking it in your for loop conditional.

```
int stop = 0;

for (int i = 0; !stop && i < 5; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j) {
        if (false) {
            stop = 1;
            break;
        }
        // Condition when true does not need 'else' if breaking.
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't that nice as the other examples if you ask me. The code looks... hard to read.

Comment: OP does **not** want to break out of the outer loop.

Comment: Indeed, I didn't see the comment below the pseudo code.  I got as far as `break out of this for loop` and made a poor assumption.  I didn't realise a break statement could be so hard to use.